# How to hide POST request on view in django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have one view which has POST and GET request. For POST request data comes from other URL. I don't use this view to POST the data. However, I have a GET request for the same view which retrieves data from the model and displays it. Now, when I open (GET request) this view it correctly shows the data. But in addition it shows text area for a POST request as well. I want to hide POST request on my view.

Code:

```
@api_view(['POST','GET',])
def TestView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
        customers_instance = Customers.objects.create(firstname=data[0]["value"],
                                            lastname=data[1]["value"],
                                            dob=data[2]["value"],
                                            emailaddress=data[3]["value"],
                                            address1=data[4]["value"],
                                            address2=data[5]["value"],
                                            city=data[6]["value"],
                                            state=data[7]["value"],
                                            postalcode=data[8]["value"])
        return HttpResponse('Data has been received by API')

    if request.method == 'GET':
        qs= Customers.objects.values('emailaddress','customer_id')
        serializer_class = CustomersKeySerializer
        return Response(serializer_class(many=True).to_representation(qs))
```

[image]

Comment: What you mean by ***" For POST request data comes from other URL"*** ? It's not relevant where the data comes from. If you disallow the POST requests to the particular view, ***it wont be accessible for any POST requests...from anywhere***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jay,

I think you should use two different views since you are dealing with two different URL's: one for GET and one for POST request.

```
@api_view(['GET',])
def TestGetView(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        qs= Customers.objects.values('emailaddress','customer_id')
        serializer_class = CustomersKeySerializer
        return Response(serializer_class(many=True).to_representation(qs))


@api_view(['POST',])
def TestPostView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
        customers_instance = Customers.objects.create(firstname=data[0]["value"],
                                        lastname=data[1]["value"],
                                        dob=data[2]["value"],
                                        emailaddress=data[3]["value"],
                                        address1=data[4]["value"],
                                        address2=data[5]["value"],
                                        city=data[6]["value"],
                                        state=data[7]["value"],
                                        postalcode=data[8]["value"])
        return HttpResponse('Data has been received by API')
```